# How to stop applications / programs starting on startup on macOS?

Tags: applications, dock, startup, system-settings, restart

I'm trying to have precise visitability of, and most importantly, **control** over which applications / programs do and do not automatically start when the OS starts up (e.g. after a reset etc).

I've tried:

- Right clicking on the icon in the dock and ensuring 'Open at Login' is unticked

  - This works some of the time, but many applications are not found in the dock

    - Examples:

      1. docker's icon after it starts is on the menu bar at the top of screen, and there's no 'Open at Login' option for it, and
      2. some programs don't have an icon in the dock **or** in the menu bar
- Following the instructions [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/turn-off-auto-program-startup-mac-59814.html), but there simply isn't a 'Login Items' button on either of my MacBooks

Any ideas?

Comment: **THIS** is why you indicate your macOS version. While the Users & Groups preference has changed over the years it has been pretty stable for the last few versions if I recall correctly. Also there is a checkmark when rebooting/shutting down asking if you want to re-open everything at login. *AND* there are things that start up automatically that have no (visible) interface to turn off and on. So tell us which macOS version and *specifically* what apps as well. Otherwise we may not be able to assist.

Comment: @SteveChambers I prefer a solution that is independent across macOS versions - one that works for multiple (preferably all) macOS versions, as I use multiple across different devices. Preferably a set of terminal commands or some low level utility (if one exists) that is preinstalled (or which can easily be installed) on different macOS versions.

Comment: @SteveChambers specifically for now though, I'm using Mojave and Big Sur.

Comment: "there are things that start up automatically that have no (visible) interface to turn off and on." - agree. It's one of the reasons for the question

Comment: Well Since Mojave `System Preferences > Users & Groups > [USERNAME] > Login Items` has been right there. If the apps that are starting are not there then you have a relaunch on login  app or apps or a launch daemon type of app.

Comment: Some programs have launch daemons/launch agents that run in the background that don't necessarily show up in System Preferences settings. These are typically located in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `System/Library/LaunchAgents`, or in `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`. However you should be very careful with removing these, especially in the System folder. Investigate about LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents before you make any changes on these